# Pyodbc execute returns NONE

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

The actual scenario is I have been provided a stored procedure by a client that should do insert operations and return me contents when I call it via a Python script using pyodbc library:

```
cursor.execute('{call SP_procedure(?,?,?....)}', parameters.....)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

When the code is executed from the script it does the insert operations but returns nothing.

When I execute the procedure in SQL CLI/studio, it does return the appropriate results.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Noted , the procedures are not designed or defined by me , I have absolute no control on it, it was provided by the client's IT team.

Comment: Then send that link to them asking them to stop using `sp_` as prefix ....

Comment: @VoltAge - When you say that you have "no control" over the SP does it mean that you are unable to modify it to add a `SET NOCOUNT ON;` statement at the beginning of the procedure if it doesn't have one?